# Trying to replicate printf behaviour about variadic paramenters

Tags: c, printf, ascii, variadic, garbage

I'm trying to replicate some `printf` functionality for education purposes, but I've encountered some `printf` behavior that I'm unable to understand. I'll try explaining with a simple example:

have this call:

```
printf(" %c %c %c", 0, 1, 2); // yes, parameters are ints not chars.
```

The output seems normal, only 3 spaces, numbers are ignored.

But taking `printf` output to a file, then using "**cat -e file**" does this:

```
 ^@ ^A ^B
```

**^@** for  0, **^A** for 1, **^B** for 2 and so on.

Here is my question, what are those symbols? How they relate to the values?

Also my own `printf`, does this as well **except for the 0 which is treated as a '\0'** char...I need to mimic `printf` exactly so I need to understand what is going on there...

I've searched about those symbols, but can't find anything. They are not memory garbage because the results are always same.

Comment: Note that the numbers are not "ignored", they just happen to be non-printable.

Comment: You asked to print the characters with ASCII codes `0`, `1`, and `2`. These are control characters, so they don't produce any output on the terminal. But they're still written to stdout, and when you redirect to the file they're stored in the file. `cat -e` shows control characters visibly.

Comment: For comparison, try `printf("%c %c %c", 65, 66, 67);`.

Comment: So why is 0 treated as a ^@ non printable character, but when i print (using write()) is treated as a '\0' char and ends the string abruptly? , non 0 unmbers are treated fine, its just the zero.

Comment: The 0 or NUL character, which cat -e shows as ^@, is special in that it's the *null character* which terminates strings in C.  So if you used `sprintf` to create a string (instead of `printf` to print to stdout), you'd seem to see the string being truncated, because it would end at the ^@.  And if you read a string containing ^@ from a file — perhaps using `fgets — it will also seem to be truncated.

Comment: But, yes, the 0 *is* the \0 char.  You need to say a little more about how this is causing you problems.

Comment: I know its the null character. What i meant is why printf prints ^@ while im getting '\0'. I'm using memset to replace the character.

Comment: Also note that `'\0'` is the terminator of *strings*, but it's still a "valid" `char`: https://godbolt.org/z/3jKc88seW

Comment: BTW, characters _are_ integers. The difference is that things like `%d` tell `printf()` to perform an int-to-text conversion, turning things like `12` into `"12"`. The `%c` format specifier does not do that; it just puts the integer on output without the to-text conversion (and with a limited range, usually 8-bits maximum).

Comment: @Lineath "Also my own printf, does this as well except for the 0 which is treated as a '\0' char..."  --> Please post the sample that fails for 0.

Comment: *Also my own printf, does this as well except for the 0 which is treated as a '\0' char* It's still not clear what you mean by this.  I think you're saying that your printf is behaving differently from the standard `printf` in some respect.  But you haven't really explained that difference, and you haven't shown us your printf code, so we can't guess.

Answer (score 4):

The `-e` option to `cat` tells it to use a particular notation for printing non-printable characters.  `^@` represents the value 0, `^A` represents the value 1, and `^B` represents the value 2.  Those are exactly the values you gave.

Answer (score 4):

Simply cat uses **caret notation** to display not printable characters. `^A` represents *1* and `^Z` represents *26*. `^@` is *0* and

- 27 - `^[`
- 28 - `^\`
- 29 - `^]`
- 30 - `^^`
- 31 - `^_`
- 127 - `^?`

Answer (score 1):

> What i meant is why `printf` prints ^@ while im getting '\0'(?)

`printf("%c", 0);` prints the *null character* to `stdout`.  What you see when viewing the output of `stdout` is not part of `stdout`, but an implementation detail of the shell/terminal program.  Print the return value of `printf()` to get its understanding of how many characters it printed.  Perhaps on `stderr` to separate it from `stdout`.

```
int count = printf(" %c %c %c", 0, 1, 2);
fprintf(stderr, "<%d>\n", count);
```

> The output seems normal, only 3 spaces, numbers are ignored.

"Seems" deserves more detail.  How was *only 3* determined?

> But taking printf output to a file, ...

What was the length of the file? 6?

> ... then using "cat -e file" does this:

Refer to [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75261111/2410359) good answer as to why you now see " ^@ ^A ^B".

---

> [I'm using memset to replace the character.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75261067/trying-to-replicate-printf-behaviour-about-variadic-paramenters#comment132806259_75261067)

is unclear as there is no `memset()` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved. Thanks to the explanations here, i realized that even i was printing the resulting string with write() i was using a pointer to iterate it so never gave a chance to actually pass over that null character.

```
write(STDOUT_FD, delta, d_length);
```

Then write() does the job correcty:

```
make test > check.txt && cat -e check.txt
own: ^@ ^A ^B$
lib: ^@ ^A ^B$
```

Also now i know about the caret notation, thanks everyone!

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1 by definition.

Comment: Why not just `write(STDOUT_FD, delta, d_length)`?

Comment: sizeof its just a good practice i was told to do, for compatibility.

Comment: About @SteveSummit, yep! i was using write() for weeks to print single chars, so i in my head was only for that! thanks!

Comment: @Lineath I thought it might have been something like that.  Calling `write` to write one character at a time is sort of like riding a bicycle with one pedal.  You have to keep stopping, and pulling the pedal back up to the top, so you can push it through another half turn.  It can be done, but it's super, frustratingly, agonizingly inefficient! :-)

Comment: `sizeof delta[0]` is a good practice to express the sizeof what `delta` points to.  `sizeof(char)` is better a `1`.

Comment: "i realized that even i was printing the resulting string with write() i was using a pointer to iterate it so never gave a chance to actually pass over that null character." --> that makes little sense as using a pointer to iterate is no the problem.  What was the true errant code?